# ConciseDateFormatter in subplots

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

Using `mdates.ConciseDateFormatter` in multiple subplots gives erroneous offset in the axis:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

dti = pd.to_datetime(["2016-08-31", "2016-09-30"])
ts0 = pd.DataFrame({"x": [0, 1]}, index=dti)
ts1 = pd.DataFrame({"x": [0, 1]}, index=dti + pd.Timedelta(365, "D"))
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=False)
ts0["x"].plot(ax=axs[0], marker="o")
ts1["x"].plot(ax=axs[1], marker="o")
dlocator = mdates.AutoDateLocator(minticks=6, maxticks=9)
axs[0].xaxis.set_major_locator(dlocator)
axs[0].xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(dlocator))
axs[1].xaxis.set_major_locator(dlocator)
axs[1].xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(dlocator))
```

[image: mdates_bug]

The figure shows the x-axis tick labels for the top plot got messed up when assigning the major locator and formatter to the bottom plot. Is there any workaround to this bug or problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- It is required to instantiate `AutoDateLocator` for each `axes`

  - See [Formatting date ticks using `ConciseDateFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks_and_spines/date_concise_formatter.html)
  - As the plot axis is formatted, the `locator` object changes, as such, it can't be reused for the subsequent `axes`.
- [`matplotlib.dates.ConciseDateFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.ConciseDateFormatter)
- [`matplotlib.dates.AutoDateLocator`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.AutoDateLocator)
- **Tested in `python 3.8.11`, `pandas 1.3.3`, `matplotlib 3.4.3`**

### Plot Setup Code

```py
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=False, figsize=(7, 7))
# axs = axs.flatten()  # required to easily index subplots, if subplots >= 2x2
ts0["x"].plot(ax=axs[0], marker="o")
ts1["x"].plot(ax=axs[1], marker="o")
```

### Option 1

```py
# instantiate AutoDateLocator
locator = mdates.AutoDateLocator(minticks=6, maxticks=9)
axs[0].xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
axs[0].xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(locator))

# instantiate AutoDateLocator
locator = mdates.AutoDateLocator(minticks=6, maxticks=9)
axs[1].xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
axs[1].xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(locator))

fig.tight_layout()
```

### Option 2

```py
for ax in axs:
    # instantiate AutoDateLocator
    locator = mdates.AutoDateLocator(minticks=6, maxticks=9)
    formatter = mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(locator)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

fig.tight_layout()
```

### Plot Result

[image]